# JBPM KIE Server Token Based Authentication

Tags: keycloak

I have successfully installed and configured JBPM 7.40.0 and Keycloak 11.0.0 on the same server instance as per the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.3.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_kie.keycloakssointegration) . I can succesfully do GET http://myserver/kie-server/services/rest/server using basic authentication. Performing the same call with a JWTToken I succesfully got from keycloak   however results in UnAuthorized. As the same user authenticates via Basic Authentication the roles are fine. Why is Oauth failing? Do I need to configure something on my JBPM install to get it to run?

Note that I am running the kie server and business central on the same wildfly instance.

Answer (score 0):

I enabled http logging on WildFly as described [here](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-web/jbosswebserver/how-do-you-configure-jboss-to-enable-http-logging) and my mistake became apparent. The secure deployment targeting the war file under consideration within the keycloak subsystem in the standalone.xml had the auth-server-url with protocoal http. I was retrieving the token from Keycloak via https. The following error then appeared

Expected 'http://kc-server/auth/realms/my-realm', but was 'https://kc-server/auth/realms/my-realm'"

Retrieving the token via http resolved the issue. Truthfully I should rather configure Wildfly to use https however as I am using self signed certificates I found it easier initially to just use http.

Comment: The exception is also apparent in the original response WWW-Authenticate response header.